# some examples for using specific searchalgorithm

Tags: algorithm

I could understand the following search algorithms:

- Constraint Satisfaction with Arc Consistency,
- Uninformed search
- A* Search
- MinMax

I would understand the definition and working principles of the above algorithm,but could you please give me some real world examples that the above algorithms will be suitable?My idea would be: For CSP with Arc Consistency,assign students to groups that each group must contain both technical and management students,and no 2 technical students in a same group.

Uniformed Search: search for a file under UNIX directoy.

A* Search: search a way (staring from home) to go to mulitple stores to buy things then get back home with minimum total travelling time.

MinMax:Go or other Chess.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Uniformed search: When the police are trying to find you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Not Sure what you mean by Arc Consistency.  An example of Constraint Satisfaction could be Sudoku ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem).
2. Uniformed Search you want to find the shops, but you have know idea where they are.(you know nothing about the search domain).  Your example does work if you have no idea where the file is.
3. A* you want to find the shops located x km away and you know you have traveled y km. (you know a heuristic)
4. Chess is probably a bad example because of the size of the search space for minmax and that players will probably not make optimal choices(but could work). Another example is reversi.  A simple example is TicTacToe.